# Deleting a node in a doubly linked list in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm learning about doubly linked lists in Java and I've found a tutorial about deleting a node with a specific key.

This is the code:

```
public Node deleteKey(int key) {
    Node current = first;
    while (current.getData() != key) {
        current = current.getNext();
        if (current == null) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    if (current == first) {
        first = current.getNext();
    } else {
        current.getPrevious().setNext(current.getNext()); 
    }

    if (current == last) {
        last = current.getPrevious();
    } else {
        current.getNext().setPrevious(current.getPrevious()); 
    }

    return current;
}
```

I want to ask you if this code is correct. In my opinion it isn't correct because he also needs to do this:

```
current.setNext(null);
current.setPrevious(null);
```

Comment: It looks correct (At this part). As @MauricePerry Said If list is empty, It fails.

Comment: It will throw an exception if the list is empty

Answer (score 5):

Calling `current.setNext(null)` and `current.setPrevious(null)` is not necessary, since after calling `deleteKey(int key)`, no `Node` of the list will contain a reference to the removed `Node` (referenced by `current`), so it doesn't matter what `Node`s the removed `Node` is referring to.

Answer (score 2):

It is not absolutely necessary to set the next and previous pointers to `null`, however, as the node is returned by the `deleteKey` method, I agree with you: it would be better to set them to `null` and prevent any memory leak.
Another problem with this code is that if the list was empty, `first` would be null, and the while expression would throw an NPE.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the next and previous of current of null as the node is removed from the list.

Remember the only way to traverse a doubly linked list is to start at the first or head node and continue till the required node or the last/tail node. If you want to delete a node you just link it's previous to it's next node and vice versa.

That being said it is not wrong to set the deleted node's next and previous to null, as this prevents you from traversing the list through that node's reference.